# Postfix Dovecot Local Deliver and Relay

Tags: postfix-mta, dovecot

I have a large aliases file, and don't want to move it into a DB table. The ask can we have an aliases entry that is delivered to Dovecot and others that are forwarded?

Played with virtual_alias_maps, etc. etc.

Can it be done ?

Comment: Aliases are processed by MTA (`postfix`) at SMTP stage, LDA (`dovecot`) do not deal with them at all.

Comment: Mail server configuration is not programming. This is off topic here.

Answer (score -1):

If MTA expands address to the alias that points to the local address, then LDA occur. If address is expanded to the alias that points to the external domain, then redirection will occur. Both types of aliases have exactly the same semantics and syntax therefore they are traditionally stored in the single file `/etc/aliases`